# Spring: Creating a truly scalable Thread Pool with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, threadpool

I have a REST API which uses Spring ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. The API internally submits callable jobs to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor which makes call to third party. Once the call is done, business logic is performed and results are returned back to the caller.

The code works fine but when the load increases then the performance becomes really bad. I am suspecting this to be the result of thread pool size for ThreadPoolTaskExecutor. So say if the concurrent users are n but we have only x number of thread(x is less then n) then the x thread will have to unnecessary wait for limited number of threads to process their request.

I want to process the third party calls in parallel but doesn't want to create a thread pool with huge number of threads.

Options for me is to use  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(y). Use it inside the method and once the process is complete close the object. This is possible but not sure about it side effects like Is it a good practice to create fixed thread pool from the method.

Other option might be to use some kind of object pool like GenericObjectPoolConfig and use it to fetch the threads.

Other option might be to set the max pool size to Integer.max and reduce the queue capacity to 1. So that each time a new request comes instead of storing the object in queue it creates a new thread.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(1);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
```

It will be helpful if anyone can share his thoughts.

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration{

   @Bean
public ConcurrentTaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor() {
    ConcurrentTaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor = new ConcurrentTaskExecutor();
    concurrentTaskExecutor.setConcurrentExecutor(getExecutor());
    return concurrentTaskExecutor;
}

private Executor getExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(30);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(75);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}
}

@Service
public class TestServiceImpl{
  @Autowired
  private ConcurrentTaskExecutor concurrentTaskExecutor;

  @Override
  @Transactional
  public DTO getDTO() {
    Callable<TESTDTO> test1Callable = new Test1Callable();
    Future<TESTDTO> testDTO1 = concurrentTaskExecutor.submit(test1Callable);

    Callable<TESTDTO> test2Callable = new Test2Callable();
    Future<TESTDTO> testDTO2 =concurrentTaskExecutor.submit(test2Callable);

    Callable<TESTDTO> test3Callable = new Test3Callable();
    Future<TESTDTO> testDTO3 =concurrentTaskExecutor.submit(test3Callable);

    // Perform logic on DTO's
    return DTO;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe the first step for your is to do some instrumentation and confirm if your suspicion is correct - _I am suspecting this to be the result of thread pool size_. You could look at solutions after confirming what the bottleneck is.

Comment: Thread pool size is the reason. Increasing the size, improves the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I really think that what you have up looks good.  All you need to do is have good performance tests to try out various values of queue capacity and pool size.  And for that matter, any other field.

With that said, there are some general guidelines you can follow.  For example if the threads are doing CPU intensive computations, then you might want to limit the pool size to 2*number of cores, or somewhere in that vicinity.  If the threads are working on IO intensive tasks (like communicating to external API's) then you can go higher.  In my own tests in the past I have noticed that return on investment trails at about 50 threads when doing IO intensive tasks on a duo core Intel.  After 50 I would stop seeing any performance increases.  But please test this yourself and verify as CPU's are always improving.  After some point adding more concurrent threads costs too much due to context switching.

Consider duplicating what those threads will be doing, possibly using remote stubs that mimic the latency of the actual API's you are calling.

Also, consider that you might be pushing downstream systems to their breaking point.  On at least one occasion we wrote very parallel code only to find out that the downstream external API we were hitting was not as parallel and was causing an outage for their other customers during our peak usages.  We accidentally DOS'd the API.

Please profile your system and check if the CPU or memory or disk IO is being strained.  If the memory, CPU, and disk IO is fine, then maybe you hitting downstream constraints.  On one occasion we were logging too much during some highly parallel code and disk IO was our bottle neck.